# Mathematica giving imaginary solutions to an equation having real roots

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

Consider the cubic equation :

$$ 336 - 1269 t + 1366 t^2 - 360 t^3 == 0 $$

When I use :

```
Solve[336 - 1269 t + 1366 t^2 - 360 t^3 == 0, t]
```

It prints me the result:

[image]

Which isn't the correct solution as the correct solutions to this equation are :

2.55983724888559, 0.4890179058058, 0.74558928975305

So, I'd like to know if there's anything wrong in my command. And I would like to know how to get the correct result.

It gives me a wrong result even if I increase the degree of the equation.

Thanks to any and all who answer.

Comment: Use [NSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) instead of `Solve`, or change the `0` on the right of your equation to `0.`

Comment: Voting to close this question because that is exactly the numerical value of the expressions `Solve` returns.  You may want to google for "casus irreducibilis".

Comment: What you call "the correct solutions" (2.55983724888559, 0.4890179058058, 0.74558928975305) are less correct than (2.55983724888559235041110012973, 0.489017905805800753623279075876, \
0.745589289753051340410065238843) which are themselves less correct than the solution given by Mathematica

Comment: I guess I'll ask: on what basis was the solution provided deemed not correct? The presence of the imaginary unit (covered in the response by @BobHanlon)? The lack of a decimal approximation (covered in documentation for `Solve`). Something else?

Answer (score 2):

While the results from [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) may appear complex, their numeric values are real (see [`casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)).

```
soln = Solve[336 - 1269 t + 1366 t^2 - 360 t^3 == 0, t]

(*  {{t -> (1/540)*(683 + 123859/
              (41070752 + 405*I*
                     Sqrt[1300537571])^(1/3) + 
            (41070752 + 405*I*
                   Sqrt[1300537571])^(1/3))}, 
   {t -> 683/540 - 
         (123859*(1 + I*Sqrt[3]))/
           (1080*(41070752 + 405*I*
                     Sqrt[1300537571])^
                (1/3)) - ((1 - I*Sqrt[3])*
              (41070752 + 405*I*
                     Sqrt[1300537571])^(1/3))/
           1080}, 
   {t -> 683/540 - 
         (123859*(1 - I*Sqrt[3]))/
           (1080*(41070752 + 405*I*
                     Sqrt[1300537571])^
                (1/3)) - ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*
              (41070752 + 405*I*
                     Sqrt[1300537571])^(1/3))/

       1080}}  *)
```

[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) will convert the radicals to [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects which evaluate to the real values you expected.

```
soln2 = soln // FullSimplify

(*  {{t -> Root[-336 + 1269 #1 - 1366 #1^2 + 360 #1^3 &, 3]}, {t -> 
   Root[-336 + 1269 #1 - 1366 #1^2 + 360 #1^3 &, 1]}, {t -> 
   Root[-336 + 1269 #1 - 1366 #1^2 + 360 #1^3 &, 2]}}  *)

soln2 // N

(*  {{t -> 2.55984}, {t -> 0.489018}, {t -> 0.745589}}  *)
```

Alternatively, use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to remove the small imaginary artifacts produced doing the evaluations with machine precision.

```
soln // N // Chop

(*  {{t -> 2.55984}, {t -> 0.489018}, {t -> 0.745589}}  *)
```

**EDIT**

Another alternative is to use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
soln3 = ComplexExpand[soln] // Simplify

(*  {{t -> (1/540)*(683 + 
            2*Sqrt[123859]*
              Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                    (405*Sqrt[1300537571])/
                      41070752]])}, 
   {t -> (1/540)*(683 - Sqrt[123859]*
              Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                    (405*Sqrt[1300537571])/
                      41070752]] - 
            Sqrt[371577]*Sin[(1/3)*
                  ArcTan[(405*Sqrt[
                          1300537571])/
                      41070752]])}, 
   {t -> (1/540)*(683 - Sqrt[123859]*
              Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                    (405*Sqrt[1300537571])/
                      41070752]] + 
            Sqrt[371577]*Sin[(1/3)*
                  ArcTan[(405*Sqrt[
                          1300537571])/
                      41070752]])}}  *)

soln3 // N

(*  {{t -> 2.55984}, {t -> 0.489018}, {t -> 0.745589}}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment `NSolve` will solve your equation

```
f[t_] := 336 - 1269 t + 1366 t^2 - 360 t^3

NSolve[f[t] == 0, t]
```

and you can also use `Reduce`,

```
Reduce[f[t] == 0 && -10 < t < 10, t];

ss = N[{ToRules[%]}]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 3}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{t, f[t]} /. ss]}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

`Solve` gives,

```
Solve[f[t] == 0 && 0 < t < 10, t];
N[%, 15]
```

> {{t -> 0.489017905805801}, {t -> 0.745589289753051}, {t -> 
>      2.55983724888559}}

I am not sure about the solutions you presented. It seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: But so will `Solve`. By not mentioning that one might get the impression that the OP is correct in his claim that `Solve` returns a wrong result.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please see the edit